# What is considered "current version" of an app in Apple App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, ios6

As you might know, at least in iOS6, the App Store app allows users to check both the **Current Version** and the **All Versions** App Store Ratings for an app. I'm about to submit an update to our app and I'm trying to decide on whether I should go with **v2.0.0** or **v1.1.0**

The reason is because we have very good ratings for the one and only version in the store, and so if I can keep those ratings "current", then I would be ok with not bumping the "major version" digits to 2, even though it's a pretty big rewrite of the original app.

Thus, does anybody know what is considered "current version"? The major version? The minor version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "current version" is the version currently in the App Store. It has nothing to do with whatever arbitrary version number you assign a release of the app. Since you have version 1.0 in the store, that is the current version. Your next update will be the new current version. It doesn't matter if you call it 2.0, 1.1, 1.0.1, or 26.